# Why did Jessica specifically mention "soccer moms fighting over bottled water" in this scene?

Tags: bird-box

In *Bird Box* (2018), Malorie didn't gave much attention to mass suicides:

> News: US authorities are advising the public to remain calm. There
>   have been no officially confirmed inst...
>
> Malorie: Well, it's in Russia, so...
>
> Jessica: Well, try telling that to the **soccer moms fighting over
>   bottled water**.

Why did Jessica specifically mention "soccer moms fighting over bottled water"?

Comment: Just look at how people are responding to the coronavirus outbreak, I guess a more accurate line would've been toilet paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that "[soccer moms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soccer_mom)" (middle-aged, middle-class suburban women) are fighting each other over a staple (bottled water) suggests that the public are actually taking the outbreak seriously.

In the [original (2014 draft) film script](https://files.meetup.com/542226/BIRD%20BOX%20%2803.10.14%29%20-%20Eric%20Heisserer%20copy.pdf), the next line also mentions [survivalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivalism).

> **MALORIE:** *It’s in Russia.*
>
> **JESSICA:** *Try telling that to the soccer moms fighting over the bottled water. I don’t want you going out there until people remember to calm the fuck down. Okay? Is Dad texting you survivalist bullshit?*

Comment: "taking the outbreak seriously" more like "overreacting to small inconvenient event". They just happened to get this one right. Don't forget the [bread and milk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6zaVYWLTkU) and now the [gloves and soap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfznPscaiDQ)